# Space Buttons equally in Layout, but with an empty slot

Tags: qt, layout, qpushbutton, qlayout

I'm trying to create a panel of buttons that will have 4 buttons, a space, and another button, all of equal space, like this:

[image: 0_1533139279983_73cdd4a9-1f62-419e-9a84-3cb4013cfad5-image.png]

I have tried to use [Spacers](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html), but it seems like those require a specific height and weight, and I would like this layout to be dynamic enough to appear correctly on any resolution, so a fixed size Spacer would not work.

I have tried to following code, but this just squishes the first 4 buttons to the top and the last one to the bottom, and doesn't space them out evenly.

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->setMargin(15);
layout->setSpacing(15);
layout->addWidget(button1, 1);
layout->addWidget(button2, 1);
layout->addWidget(button3, 1);
layout->addWidget(button4, 1);
layout->addWidget(button5, 2, Qt::AlignBottom);
layout->addStretch();

buttonPnl->setLayout(layout);
```

I also tried using a QGridLayout and specifying the height of each row, but this looks the same as the previous example.

```
QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
gridLayout->setMargin(15);
gridLayout->setSpacing(15);
gridLayout->addWidget(button1, 0, 0);
gridLayout->addWidget(button2, 1, 0);
gridLayout->addWidget(button3, 2, 0);
gridLayout->addWidget(button4, 3, 0);
gridLayout->addWidget(button5, 5, 0);
gridLayout->setRowStretch(0, 1);
gridLayout->setRowStretch(1, 1);
gridLayout->setRowStretch(2, 1);
gridLayout->setRowStretch(3, 1);
gridLayout->setRowStretch(4, 1);
gridLayout->setRowStretch(5, 1);
```

How can I create a dynamic layout that will display my buttons correctly at any reasonable resolution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit ``hacky-slash'' but... the easiest way to get the desired behaviour is probably to define a spacer class that inherits from `QPushButton` but has an empty `paintEvent` definition...

```
class spacer: public QPushButton {
  using super = QPushButton;
public:
  using super::super;
protected:
  virtual void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
    }
};
```

Then just make sure you instantiate it with a text string that's in keeping with the other buttons so that it has a suitable return value from `sizeHint()`.  So (based on your own example)...

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(button1);
layout->addWidget(button2);
layout->addWidget(button3);
layout->addWidget(button4);

/*
 * Add a spacer using the text from button4 as a reference.
 */
layout->addWidget(new spacer(button4->text()));
layout->addWidget(button5);
layout->addStretch();

buttonPnl->setLayout(layout);
```

This gives me something like...

[image]